# Name of this recursive Algorithm?

Tags: java, list, algorithm, recursion

Assignment - Write two Java programs!

The first one uses a recursive algorithm.

The second one uses a non-recursive algorithm.

They must determine if a list (of any length) has the following pattern:

Cell[0] = 2;

Cell[1] = 2squared = 4;

Cell[3] = 4squared = 16;

The pattern is where any value of a cell [n+1] is equal to the square of the value in cell[n].

e.g: 2, 4, 16, 256, 65536, 4294967296

**Question:**

Can anyone point me to a code example, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is simply a [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence). I don't know if the sequence with *s(n) = (s(n - 1))^2* has a special name. Have you tried to implement this yourself? A simple loop and a primitive array is all you need.

Comment: It's called A001146: https://oeis.org/A001146.

Comment: Please read  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `BigInteger`.  But even then, I limited the number of terms to `8` as they get quite large.

Iterative call.

```
BigInteger[] terms = iterative(8);
for (BigInteger b : terms) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
System.out.println("Sequence array for iteration is " + 
(validate(terms) ? "valid" : "invalid"));
```

Prints

```
2
4
16
256
65536
4294967296
18446744073709551616
340282366920938463463374607431768211456
Sequence array for iterative is valid
```

Recusive call

```
terms = recursive(8);
for (BigInteger b : terms) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
System.out.println("Sequence array for recursion is " + 
(validate(terms) ? "valid" : "invalid"));
```

Prints

```
2
4
16
256
65536
4294967296
18446744073709551616
340282366920938463463374607431768211456
Sequence array for recursion is valid
```

Validation method

```
public static boolean validate(BigInteger[] terms) {
    for (int i = 1; i < terms.length; i++) {
        if (!terms[i].equals(terms[i-1].pow(2))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The iterative approach.

- simply initialize the first term to `Biginteger.TWO`.
- then iterate over the list raising each previous term to the power of `2`.

```
public static BigInteger[] iterative(int n) {
   if (n < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be > 0");
    }
    BigInteger[] terms = new BigInteger[n];
    terms[0] = BigInteger.TWO; // 2^2^0 = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        terms[i] = terms[i-1].pow(2);
    }
    return terms;
}
```

The recursive approach.

Although it can be done without a helper method using one is more straightforward and efficient.

- allocate the array based on `n`
- initialize the `0th` element to `2`.
- return immediately if `n == 1`
- otherwise, invoke the helper method.

```
public static BigInteger[] recursive(int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be > 0");
    }
    BigInteger[] terms = new BigInteger[n];
    terms[0] = BigInteger.TWO;
    if (n == 1) {
        return terms;
    }
    return recursiveHelper(terms, n);
}
```

- recursively call the method until `n == 2`
- then simply assign the `n-1` element the value in `n-2` raised to the power of 2
- then return the terms.

```
private static BigInteger[] recursiveHelper(BigInteger[] terms, int n) {
     if (n > 2) {
        recursiveHelper(terms,n-1);
     }
     terms[n-1] = terms[n-2].pow(2);
     return terms;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer. It's genuinely appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific algorithm for this problem that I know of, but here are code examples:

Recursive:

```
public boolean validSequenceFromIndex(int[] sequence, int index) {
  if (index >= sequence.length - 1) return true; // If it is the last index or
  // greater, then it works.

  if (sequence[index + 1] != sequence[index] * sequence[index]) return false; // The
  // pattern does not hold.

  return validSequenceFromIndex(sequence, index + 1); // The sequence is valid at this
  // index, check the rest of the sequence.
}
```

Notice here that the parameters here are an `int[] sequence` and an `int index` while the problem should only give you an `int[] sequence`. Simply write a function like the following:

```
public boolean validSequence(int[] sequence) {
  return validSequenceFromIndex(sequence, 0); // Checks if the sequence is valid starting
  // from the beginning (essentially the whole sequence.
}
```

which should transfer only having the sequence as a parameter to using a sequence and an index.

Non-recursive:

```
public boolean validSequence(int[] sequence) {
  for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++) { // Loop through entirety of the
  // except for the last index.
    if (sequence[i + 1] != sequence[i] * sequence[i]) return false;
  }
  // All indices checked, the sequence works:
  return true;
}
```

Hope this made sense to you!

Comment: null_awe Thank you for your help, I'm grateful.